# Java - SimpleDateFormat UTC - unparseable date GMT+0000 (UTC)

Tags: java, android, parsing, datetime, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse this Date `Mon Sep 21 2015 14:30:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)` but I get a Parse Exception.

```
W/System.err﹕ java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Sep 21 2015 14:30:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)" (at offset 0)
W/System.err﹕ at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
```

I've tried:

```
             JSONObject datamsj = (JSONObject) args[0];
             try {
                    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
                    TimeZone tz2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Bogota");
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (z)");
                    sdf.setCalendar(cal);
                    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(datamsj.getString("fc")));

                    cal.setTimeZone(tz2);
                    Date date = cal.getTime();
                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
                    messageTextDate = df.format(date);
                    messageText = datamsj.getString("msj");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
```

But doesn't works so the question is: What is the format that I have to use to parse that Date?

Comment: could be a matter of locale. your date is in english.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the `TimeZone` and `Calendar` here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just edited it with the full code,

Comment: can you post the piece of code that you are using to parse that date? 
I tested you SimpleDateFormat and it works for the string input.

Comment: @RodrigoGomes ok, is that enough?

Comment: I got parse normally using:
`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)");`

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly and setting the Locale.